# Count the number of columns populated in a row

Tags: mysql, sql, qsqlquery

I have a table of this style in sql:

| id | FirstName | LastName | Age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Williams | 25 |
| 2 | Anne |  | 23 |

I want to count the number of columns filled in each row, as shown below.

| id | FirstName | LastName | Age | PopulatedColumns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Williams | 25 | 4 |
| 2 | Anne |  | 23 | 3 |

Does anyone know how to make a script that does this count in sql? But I didn't want to specify the name of the columns, because I have a very large table and it is not practical to put the name of all the columns. Is there a way to do this agnostic? Without putting names?

Comment: You either have to use names or create a sql statement based on information_schema.columns and submit to dynamic sql

Comment: But when I do dynamic sql ql, I can only get the name of the columns and I can't do the math I need. Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 2):

IN MySQL, you can use arithmetic:

```
select t.*,
       ( (id is not null) + (firstname is not null) + (lastname is not null) + (age is not null)
       ) as populated_columns
from t;
```

Comment: Can you do this without entering the name of the columns? Do a kind of cycle that runs through all the columns?

Comment: @anonymous6 . . . I am not aware of any such functionality in MySQL.

Comment: Just build your select in Excel.